# Java8 Parallel HTTP calls

Tags: java-8, java.util.concurrent, asynchttpclient

First thing first, this question is for Java8.

Having said that, let's go to the problem in hand.

- I have to make 2000 http calls with different parameters. Below is the URL
  https://stat.ripe.net/data/looking-glass/data.json?resource=IP-PREFIX
- The API put a restriction of maximum of 8 concurrent calls.
- I need to process response of each HTTP call later.

I am new to java and there seems to be so many different ways to accomplish this. However, I am not sure which one is the correct one. Also, limit of concurrent calls also makes it challenging for me to solve.

**Can someone please point me to the Java topic which I need to learn?**

Thanks for your time. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think CompletableFuture is a good candidate

Answer (score 1):

On top of my head

- Apache HttpClient
- Spring-Boot @Async, threadPoolTaskExecutor limit to maxPoolSize = 8

That should do it.

**Edited**
If you do not want to use Spring, you can just use ForkJoinPool with Stream. Check this out -> https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-parallel-streams-custom-threadpool

Answer (score 1):

IMO, If your project is developed using Spring framework, then I would suggest you to go with `WebFlux`. It is the implementation of RxJava, a [reactive programming](http://reactivex.io/) approach. The documentation link is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html). It includes an HTTP client, which supports non-blocking, called [`WebClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client) with which you can make HTTP calls.

Otherwise, `CompletableFuture` with `ExecutorService` having customized threadpool configuration depending on your API concurrency. This will be the good option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have mention this in my question, that using framework is not the option in my case.
I am going to look at completableFuture and ExecutorService. If you have some example link handy, it would be of great help. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `CompletableFuture` is the option that I would chose.

Comment: You can use Baeldung resource. It has beginner level tutorials